# What is this screen on android and how to open it?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, shader

[image]

Does anyone know how to launch this kind of UI on Android? I managed to launch it somehow by clicking power and one of the volume buttons, but I could not reproduce it ever since.

Comment: Can you explain the problem in a little more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On a mobile device, use a three-finger double tap.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@12.1/manual/features/rendering-debugger.html#how-to-access

Comment: Bless your soul, kind man)